# Arabic font not supported in javascript with Mozilla FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Arabic text not support in url path in Mozilla and Chrome? How to process arabic text as url?

At the same Internet explorer will be supported.

Please refer the screen shot as well.

**Mozilla:**
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD1B1973CA40AEF6%21110

**IE**
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD1B1973CA40AEF6%21109

Comment: I would copy these images as Code in your questions - you will have more people read it there as "error" then visiting your onedrive ...

Comment: If You can give us link to Your page or at least page code - especially header, then someone may help You

Comment: I have added the comment for the image in ondrive